# Вектор структур. Проблема реализаций

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры, вектор, динамические-структуры

Можно ли реализовать вектор структур так, чтобы в цикле не пришлось постоянно добавлять в него новые структуры вручную, то есть сделать его динамическим . имею ввиду, что  работать это должно как динамический массив структур, когда, при работе в цикле, он самостоятельно создает в себе новые структуры одного и того же типа.
Возможно ли это или просто стоит пользоваться обычным массивом структур?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вектор и так работает, как динамический массив. Однако это не подразумевает, что он должен сам что-то создавать.

Comment: user7860670 вы имеете ввиду std::vector, но человек может не знать о его существовании

Comment: Ничего не понятно, покажите кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Нет у вас не получится так сделать. Вектор просто является контейнером, он не может создавать объекты как вам вздумается. Придется цикле объявлять каждую структуру.